# Need a validation for specific params of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need write validation for `role` parameter of `accounts_controller`. If records with `role` `admin` only one, this record cannot update attribute `role` to `user`.

This validation must close security bug. But I don't know how it write.

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to accounts_path if account.update(role: params[:role])
  end
end
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :admin]
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role", default: 0
end
```

I trying write something like this: `validate :role, less_than_or_equal_to: 1` but it didn't works.

Answer (score 1):

account.rb

```
validate :the_last_admin

protected

def the_last_admin  
  if Account.admin.count < 2
    errors.add(:role, 'You are the last admin!')
  end
end
```